# Electron IPC Reference Error

Tags: javascript, electron, ipc

I'm a total noob, first month into javascript, creating a simple Win application in Electron. I need to send information from index.html/index.js to session.html. I already did it successfully via IPC, while creating the session.html from the main process/menu. But now, when I create that new BrowserWindow (session.html) from the index.js, I get the reference error. I can't seem to find the solution to this, despite it seeming to be a very simple issue.

So, I execute this function to create a new BrowserWindow:

```
addWin = function() {
  addWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    show: false,
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    title: 'Process'
  })

  addWindow.loadURL(url.format({
    pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'session.html'),
    protocol: 'file:',
    slashes: true
  }))

  addWindow.once('ready-to-show', () => {
    addWindow.show()
  })

  addWindow.on('close', function() {
    addWindow = null
  })
}
```

At the same time sending information from the submitted form, via IPC:

```
ipcRenderer.send('process:add', minutes)
```

Main process (main.js) understands my message and shows it in console":

```
ipcMain.on('process:add', function(e, minutes){
console.log(apjoms)
addWindow.webContents.send('#minutes', minutes)})
```

But, since it has no reference for the "addWindow", the session.html doesn't get the message, and the app shows reference error for "addWindow":

```
ipcRenderer.on('process:add', function(e, minutes) {
  var minutesText = document.createTextNode(minutes);
  li.appendChild(minutesText);
  ul.appendChild(li);
});
```

So the question is simple - how can I let the main.js see what "addWindow", defined in index.js means?

P.S. I tried to define the "addWin" function in the main.js and set it to global, while executing it on index with "remote.getGlobal". The function itself worked fine, but the main process still didn't see the "addWindow" being inside the "global.addWin" function.

Comment: Could you please help us to understand by posting here a Pastebin or something with `index.js', `main.js`, `index.html` as well as `session.html` please ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `event.sender` for accessing the `webContents` sent the event.

```
ipcMain.on('process:add', (event, minutes) => {
  event.sender.send('#minutes', minutes)
})
```

Read docs section [how to send message with ipcMain](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-main#sending-messages)

---

*BTW, you can simply structure your app/code the way you want to use it. If a function should be aware of a variable they have to share the same scope usually.
So you can simply put the `ipcMain` listeners and `BrowserWindow` initialization in the same js file.*